# Creating Variables at Runtime in Java

Tags: java, variables, integer

In my code I have a pretty big loop and I need to create a new variable at the end of each iteration (integers). Is this possible? I read about a ScriptEngineManager class, but I'm not sure if this will be able to help. I suppose I could create a bunch of integers equal to 0, but I'm not exactly sure how many times I will need to create a new variable (it depends on the conditions of the loop). Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Question says Java, tag says Javascript, question body just confuses. Is it Java or Javascript? They're two different (**completely** different) things you know. What exactly to you mean by "creating variables"?

Comment: Perhaps he's using JavaScript through the `ScriptEngine` API.  Still, the question is very vague.  We need to see the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I believe I meant Java... I'm not sure the differences really. Isn't one for web applets or something?

Comment: I'm guessing it's Java because he referenced ScriptEngineManager and class. Retagging...

Comment: @Descartes, Java and JavaScript are completely different, despite the names.  Java is the one used for applets.

Comment: I had no idea. This is the link to the API i normally use: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/, and when I search for the ScriptEngine class, I can't find it anywhere. I suppose that class is for JavaScript, while I use Java.

Comment: The link is to the Java API, so that's cleared up.  It would still be helpful if you post the relevant code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array. In Javascript, place `var results = []` before your loop and append results using `results.push(value)`. In Java, you'll want to use an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). (Those are very different languages, by the way.)

Comment: I think I am coding in Java. I can't believe what an amateur mistake.. to not know what language I'm using. Sorry. The 'var results = []' doesn't look familiar to me. Thanks

Comment: @Descartes -- Matthew's answer is still valid. If you need to store a variable number of values, then use a collection, such as an `ArrayList` or a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

> Hopefully this makes sense.

Unfortunately, it doesn't.

In Java it makes no sense to create variables on the fly.  It is extremely difficult to do, and once you have done it they are extremely difficult to use.  (By contrast, it is easy to do in Javascript ...)

However, this just means that you need to do what you are trying to in a different way.  For instance, the following does a computation in a loop and then saves the results in an (existing) `ArrayList` variable:

```
    List<Integer> results = ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (...) {
        // Do computation ...
        int result = ...
        results.add(result);
    }
    // Now we have all of the results in 'results'
```

Or, if you want to bind each of the results to a distinct name, you could do something like this:

```
    Map<String, Integer> results = HashMap<String, Integer>();
    while (...) {
        // Do computation ...
        String name = ...
        int result = ...
        results.put(name, result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way that i have implemented and helped me to fix my solution easily without much hurdles.

// Creating the array List

```
List accountList = new ArrayList(); 




for(int k=0;k < counter;k++){
        accountList.add(k, (String)flowCtx.getValueAt("transitId"+m));
}
```

Iterating the loop and adding the objects into the arraylist with the index.

//Retrieving the object at run time with the help of the index

```
String a = accountList.get(i));
```

Comment: what is "flowCtx" here?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to declare variables in java at runtime. But java provides java.util.map, which can be used like in the example below. We can assume that the key is the variable name.

`Map<String, Object> declareVariableRuntime= new HashMap<String, Object>(); declareVariableRuntime.put("variableName", new Object());`