# Creating new variables automatically as the user needs them

Tags: java, arrays, variables, dynamic

I have to design a program that would be for an imaginary company as a project for my computer Science AP class. The Program will track the names of workers, hours they work, their pay rate, and if they worked overtime how much they get for it. We have to create the program in the mind set of not knowing the exact number of worker, Which means the program will loop till the user is done adding workers and hours information in then displays it at the end to show all the data and how much the company has to pay each worker. 
My thought process on this was to have a loop for the main program and let the user enter in the name, hours, rate, etc. until their done. But the road block I run into is that because it would be using the same variable over and over again, it wont be able to call it up at the end. Is their a way to automatically create variable as needed then be able to call them up at the end. If not what is a better way to go about writing this program.

so far I have tried looking at using:
Arrays
building a class

Comment: You can't automatically create variables in the way you're describing, but you can create data structures -- like a `Map` -- that dynamically keep track of values associated with different keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Variables at Runtime in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140463/creating-variables-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: Use a temporary object and set the input information. After you have the input for one Employee, add it to the array and start over with a new object. And in the end iterate through the array

Comment: You need to store the number of workers and corresponding hours of work into a 2D array. Use that to calculate and output as well. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Either you can use `ArrayList` or else if you just wanted to use `Array` then to add an element into the `Array` you can simply copy the contents of this array to a temporary array and then increase it's size by one by re-initializing it and then copy back the contents from that temp Array into this array and follow the circle, as many times as you want.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is define an object.

```
public class Worker {
    private String name;
    //...

    //getter/setters
}
```

And maintain a list

```
List<Worker> list = new ArrayList<Worker>(); //which grows automatically .
```

And instantiate the object for each entry and add to the list.