# Can we build and use a string on the LHS of an assignment?

Tags: java, variables, syntax

I know its kind of funny question to ask. I was wondering if this could be done at all?

```
Class foo {

public static void main(String [] args){
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)

//build string obji where i =0..5
//use the built string using stringbuilder and use the built string in this experssion
foo <built string> = new foo();

System.out.println(obj1.somemethod(i));

}
}

public somemethod(i){

return ("I am objet"+i)

}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140463/creating-variables-at-runtime-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Variables aren't created dynamically at execution time. Just create a `Map<String, Foo>` instead, or possibly just a `Foo[]`.

It's not clear why you even want multiple variables in this case... but then it *is* just pseudo-code...

Comment: thanks Jon for the answer " variables aren't created dynamically"